# Check AllowAnonymousAttribute in Web API

Tags: c#, security, authentication, asp.net-web-api

**System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor** has method **IsDefined** which helps to determine whether one or more instances of the specified attribute type are defined for this member.

**System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor** does not have this method.

How can I check **AllowAnonymousAttribute** using HttpActionDescriptor?

Answer (score 10):

I found. I can use **GetCustomAttributes** method. For example (from AuthorizeAttribute implementation):

```
private static bool SkipAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
  if (!Enumerable.Any<AllowAnonymousAttribute>((IEnumerable<AllowAnonymousAttribute>) actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>()))
    return Enumerable.Any<AllowAnonymousAttribute>((IEnumerable<AllowAnonymousAttribute>) actionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>());
  else
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The answer by @FireShock is correct, here is a version that I think is easier to read:

```
private static bool ShouldSkipAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    return 
        actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>(true).Any() ||
        actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>(true).Any();
}
```